# .htaccess works on Apache server, but not on FTP directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, ftp, xampp

I recently found the use of a .htaccess file to edit the URL of my webpages. This is done with mod_rewrite (Apache). I use XAMPP and the working files are inside of the appropriate htdocs folder. While in the local directory, the .htaccess file does the job and it edits the URL. I have a domain name that I've been working on and periodically update the working files to that. When I upload these files to the domain through FTP, the .htaccess file doesn't work correctly, as you can imagine since Apache modules have no way of working on a web directory. So my question is, how do I make a .htaccess file work in a web directory without Apache's mod_rewrite module?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to have htaccess files affect FTP URL's  (e.g. `ftp://somehost.com/dir/path/file.txt`)?

Comment: Essentially. I was trying to explain it the best I could. I'll make it more cut and dry. I'm building a site and have a local folder that I work on the files. I currently have that folder in htdocs in XAMPP currently to troubleshoot some php work: localhost/site/index.php. There is a .htaccess file in the directory. Since Apache is on, it works fine. I then upload those files to the website domain: http://www.mysite.com/index.php. There the .htaccess file doesn't work since the page is not running through Apache. So, yes. How do I make the .htaccess file work in the web directory.

Comment: @user2045366, that is great observation. I tried renaming the file x.htaccess and then uploading it via FTP. However, it still did not work that way or when I renamed the file back to .htaccess in the web directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not sufficiently clear. URL rewriting won't work if you're just accessing the static files (i.e. `file:///home/user/www/index.html`) rather than going through the Apache server (`http://localhost/~user/index.html`) since Apache will never process the request.

Perhaps your .htaccess file is not being uploaded properly? Some programs will complain a bit when you try to upload strangely named files, such as those beginning with a period.